# What should be used instead of raw filter?

Tags: theming, display-suite, 9

[Drupal 9 theming documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/how-to-prepare-your-drupal-7-or-8-site-for-drupal-9/preparing-for-use-of-twig#s-template-facing-twig-2-changes) indicates that the Twig raw filter is deprecated in favor of [`verbatim`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/verbatim.html).

The [ds-field-expert.html.twig](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ds/-/blob/8.x-3.x/templates/ds-field-expert.html.twig#L16) template uses `raw` to render the input in the prefix and suffix field, which is often HTML.

```
{{- settings['prefix']|raw -}}
```

`verbatim` in the Twig 2 documentation is not a filter, but instead wraps around content in the template, so wrapping the line of code does not actually go and get the prefix/suffix content. It just renders the twig.

What should I use instead of `raw` in this case so the markup I enter into the prefix and suffix field of a Display Suite expert field template renders as HTML and not plain text?
Will this template break in Drupal 9?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The raw *filter* is still fine to use. The filter is not deprecated, only the raw *tag*.

From the [Drupal 9 theming documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/how-to-prepare-your-drupal-7-or-8-site-for-drupal-9/preparing-for-use-of-twig#s-template-facing-twig-2-changes):

> As of Twig 1.x, the raw **tag** is deprecated in favor of verbatim.

Looking at the [Twig 2.x documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html), you'll notice that the raw *filter* is not deprecated.

However, in the [Twig 1.x documentation for the verbatim tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/verbatim.html) you can see that it replaced the raw *tag* in Twig 1.12. This is the cause of the deprecation in the Drupal 9 theming guide.

Ironically, there’s a notice at the bottom of that page that says the change was to help prevent confusion between the raw tag and raw filter.

> The verbatim tag works in the exact same way as the old raw tag, but was renamed to avoid confusion with the raw filter.