# is there a twig filter to correct the HTML?

Tags: theming

the slice filter on html code can generate invalid html that can cause in cascade JS errors

```
 {% set text = paragraph.field_verbatim_text.value %}
 {% if text|striptags|length > 300 %}
    {{ text|slice(0, 310)|raw }} [&hellip;]<a class="verbatim__suite" aria-label="{{ 'Read the full text'|t }}"
                                                       href="#verbatim-{{ paragraph.id() }}"
                                                       data-open="verbatim-{{ paragraph.id() }}">{{ 'Read more'|t }}</a>
```

Comment: That seems dangerous.  Why not just strip the tags from the sliced part?

Comment: `|raw` is to be avoided.

Comment: @Patrick Kenny because the code html is displayed

Comment: @cileven could u please develop why ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299321/what-should-be-used-instead-of-raw-filter

Comment: It is absolutely dangerous to use `|raw` because it does not filter output. That ^ question is about whether `|raw` was deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the insecure `|raw` filter use the render element `processed_text`. This applies the filters of the text format and marks the filtered result as safe so that you don't need the `|raw` filter anymore:

```
{% set text_sliced = {
  '#type':   'processed_text',
  '#text':    paragraph.field_verbatim_text.value|slice(0, 310),
  '#format':  'basic_html',
} %}

{{ text_sliced }}
```

Most text formats should correct the HTML out of the box. If the text format the field uses now doesn't work, configure a custom text format for this purpose and enable the "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" filter.

---

**Never output user input unfiltered**

The [link in the comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/314820/is-there-a-twig-filter-to-correct-the-html#comment402728_314820) is about the [raw filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html) not being deprecated, a false alarm when you are confusing it with the verbatim tag. Nonetheless, the security issue is about bypassing the autoescape mechanism, in Drupal enabled by default for any template. One way is the raw filter, but there are many others, in Twig and PHP. Only do this if you are sure it's safe. User input should never be considered as safe.